# Selecting display language using batch script, W2K8 / W2K12

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, language-packs

For both **Server 2008 Standard R2** and **Server Standard 2012**, I need to use a command script (not PowerShell) to change the display language. I would prefer a common approach for both types of server and either LIP or MUI - but I'll be happy even if I need distinct solutions for each of these four cases.

Comment: Why not PowerShell?

Comment: As I understand (from other engineers I've asked), the context which my script is called must call a CMD script. My experience is mostly with Unix-like systems, so I'm out of my depth here. But, I _think_ it's something like a CMD process is explicitly given my script to process. (And the whole solution must fit in that single script file.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intlcfg.exe

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722068%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

You can run the intlcfg command on an offline Windows image or on a running Windows operating system.

The Intlcfg.exe tool is installed in the Tools folder of the Windows OPK or Windows AIK. (Not installed with windows, you have to download and install)

get the .exe from: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5753

IF this solves your problem, please mark as answered.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was pulled off this task before completing it, so I can't say if it would have been enough, but it did take me much further towards a solution. I was able to "package" your suggestions into my hand-off for others to work on. Hopefully, they will come back here to finalize the conversation. Hopefully...